# Binarize credit card digits before OCR

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to binarize a credit card digits using OpenCV so that an ocr will reconize them.

so after the segmentation stage and the cropping,i did these steps:

1.convert tje image to grayscale image.

2.Histogram equalization.

3.GaussianBlur with (3,3) kernel `GaussianBlur(digit,bluredImg,cv::Size(3,3),9);`

4.Threshold(Sauvola method).

here are some of my results but i think they are noisy and insufficient for the ocr:

links to the Original images:

http://s22.postimg.org/rqnlgz1od/image.jpg

If you have some tips to enhance my binarization quality please share it with me (code will be great).

Comment: Update 14.2.14:

i used Stroke Width algorithm as mentioned here: http://rnd.azoft.com/algorithm-identifying-barely-legible-embossed-text-image/

results are good on clean cards,but cards with textures are still problem.

Comment: Image link is broken

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't apply a "binarize" step at this image. I'd first try to remove noise by elminating pixels that differ too much from their neighbours ("salt & pepper filter" because it removes black & white spots)

Comment: any sugestion how to remove noise from this 3d digit stracture?

Comment: Considering the noise has a distinct "spot" component, yes, use a salt&pepper filter to remvoe the noise